# regex How to find the last occurrence of char using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I ran a `dir /s` command to list files in folders & sub-folders, and to show the file size. My issue is that I use a "," as a separator between the file name and size.

*Is their any way to find the last comma in the and replace it with";"?*

My text file looks like this:

```
H:\IP Phones, Mobile Information.xls,152064 
H:\Master Sheet Updated.xlsx,46446
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the comma manually using the Sublime text replace?

Comment: Search using `,(?!.*,)` and replace using `;`

Comment: `dir /s` does not show the file size. Is the file size listed as *a part of the file name*??!!

Comment: ,([^,]*)$ and replace with ;$1 or ;\1

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match a comma that is not followed by `.*` (any number of any character) and a comma.

```
,(?!.*?,)
```

Then just use the `Replace...` functionality in Sublime `(Ctrl+H)` and it should work.